# Php script running few times a day with no CRON?

Tags: php, cron

Hey!
i'm looking for some way that can help me in task like this:
write a function that every 2 days clear content of XML file. Do this with no CRON or similar tools, just PHP.
So far i've never done time-related-run script so is there a way to make it with only PHP?
I assume that everything what functions does is without users ingerention, so i try function sleep(), but i think there must be better solution.
Anyone know way to help me?

Comment: What is the reason to not use CRON or similar tools?

Comment: dunno, but i must find way to do this in another way and thats pain in my ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into running your script as a daemon. PEAR's System_Daemon class manages a lot of this functionality.  You can take a look at http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/create_daemons_in_php/ for a good tutorial on how to set up a daemon.

Cron is obviously better for a timed task, but if cron really isn't available, this might be an option.

Comment: A basic daemon isn't very difficult.  Just copy the sample code and add your functionality.

Answer (score 4):

On every request check modification or creation date of file.
If current time minus file time is greater than 2 days - delete file or clear content.

Request in this case is poor resolution clock. Generally checking file time (stat) is quite fast operation.

Answer (score 1):

There are services that call your scripts at given times.

[ONLINE CRON SERVICES](http://www.onlinecronservices.com/)

Comment: As of today (22nd July 2019), the website is broken, giving a 403 response status.

Answer (score 0):

Without Cron or leaving your browser open, i'm not sure this is possible?

Comment: Was that sarcastic? I'm never sure on SO

Answer (score 0):

Letting the script `sleep()` for 2 days is no good idea. Use a [webcron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webcron).

Comment: Well, something has to invoke the script. If you cannot use anything but PHP (insane requirement), the script must never quit. That means you'll have to let it `sleep()`. You even cannot do `system('at ...')` because at is not part of your script nor written in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When the reason for no cronjobs is, that you cannot define cronjobs on your server, maybe you can call a script on another (local) machine that makes a HTTP request every other day which fires your PHP script?

Comment: i cant do this way also, everything must me automaticly and done from the level of my script

Answer (score 0):

If your script is fast to execute you can use an "user based cron".

-You save somwhere the last execution time
-Each visitor trigger a check on the last execution time
-if the execution time exceed the defined duration the script is executed

It can be a good solution if your script don't need an exact execution timing and is very quick to execute (the user which trigger the execution should not be impacted)

Answer (score 0):

This will run your script for you every 2 days (or specify number of days)
http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule the jobs using a MySQL database or a file as described [here](http://www.crankberryblog.com/2010/php-cron-job-without-using-cron-tab-cron-alternative-with-mysql-or-just-txt).

WordPress is also using the same method when cron jobs doesn't available or not been configured.